# Infinite family of monogenic cyclic quartic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

I am currently reading a paper (masters' thesis, in fact) from 2008 where it is mentioned that it is not currently known whether there exist infinitely many monogenic cyclic quartic fields (i.e., those cyclic quartic fields whose ring of integers admit a power basis). It has been 15 years, is this still the case today?

Comment: Theorem 4.1 here https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39302592.pdf claims an infinite family.